# Find data from date in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, find

I have some data in MongoDB, I want to find data for particular date, But in DB it is stored in ISODate() formate with time, Something like this,

```
{ 
"_id": ObjectId("5e578771cd0d3b7660deb7ca"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-02-27T16:38:20.444+0000"),
  "createdAt": ISODate("2020-02-27T16:38:20.444+0000")
}
```

But I want to get this doc. using only string date, Like,
db.collection.find({ createdAt: "2020-02-27" });

I tried to do it by creating range,

```
setFream1 = new Date(new Date("2020-02-27").setHours(0,0,0,0));
setFream2 = new Date(new Date("2020-02-27").setHours(23,59,59,999));


db.collection.find({ createdAt: { $gte: new Date(setFream1), $lte: new Date(setFream2) } });
```

I think it will work, But is there any other better way.
Thank You!

Comment: Define better. "2020-02-27" will be parsed as UTC, so `new Date("2020-02-27").setHours(0,0,0,0)` may well produce a time value for the start of 2020-02-26 or 2020-02-28 depending on host timezone settings. `new Date(2020, 1, 28)` is less code and has predictable results.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest and optimized approach is to use `moment` library for this.

You can install `moment` using this:

```
npm i moment
```

Then require it like this:

```
var moment=require("moment");
```

Then use it like this:

```
setFream1=moment("2020-02-27 00:00:00.000").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");
setFream2 =moment("2020-02-27 23:59:59.999").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");
```

Comment: Comparing `Date` values with **strings** is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Moment parses string into Date object.

Comment: The bad point is `.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")` which creates a string rather than a Date object.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
db.collection.find(
   {
      createdAt: {
         $gte: moment("2020-02-27").startOf("day").toDate(),
         $lte: moment("2020-02-27").endOf("day").toDate()
      }
   }
);
```

Comment: moment("2020-02-27").startOf("day").toDate() this will output Thu Feb 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: It depends on your client settings, I get `ISODate("2020-02-26T23:00:00Z")` - but where is the problem? It is still a valid `Date` object and comparison with `createdAt` will work fine because it is also a `Date`.

Comment: Will comparison work?? Because I have never tried it in this way. Can you tell please.

Comment: Yes, of course it works. Even when you generate `moment` on local time it works, because comparisons are always done based on UTC time.